# I am searching an optimal way to change variable categories in dummy variables

Tags: r, dummy-variable, grepl

I have some patients who receive different treatments at different times.
I want to change the treatment they have received into a binary variable that takes the value of 1 if the patient has received the drug at least once and the value of 0 if they have never received it.

I managed to do this but in a tedious way, which could be difficult with dozens of different types of drugs.

I would like to optimize my code which mainly avoids creating all the binary variables related to the drug one by one.

```
id<-c(rep("A",7),rep("B",4))
medoc<-c("par","mor","mor","par","sed","sed",
         "sed","cur","sed","cur","sed")

mydata<-data.frame(id,medoc)

mydata2<-mydata%>%group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(medoc_str=paste(unique(medoc),collapse  = " "))%>%
  distinct(id,.keep_all = TRUE)

mydata2$par<-NA
mydata2$mor<-NA
mydata2$sed<-NA
mydata2$cur<-NA

mydata2$par<-ifelse(
  grepl("par",mydata2$medoc_str)==TRUE,1,0
)

mydata2$mor<-ifelse(
  grepl("mor",mydata2$medoc_str)==TRUE,1,0
)

mydata2$sed<-ifelse(
  grepl("sed",mydata2$medoc_str)==TRUE,1,0
)

mydata2$cur<-ifelse(
  grepl("cur",mydata2$medoc_str)==TRUE,1,0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it, you want to dummify your variables.
We can do it with `tidyr::pivot_wider` too, but I really like to use specific libraries to do it very easily. I like the `fastDummies` package:

```
library(fastDummies)

dummy_cols(mydata, select_columns = 'medoc')

   id medoc medoc_cur medoc_mor medoc_par medoc_sed
1   1   par         0         0         1         0
2   1   mor         0         1         0         0
3   1   mor         0         1         0         0
4   1   par         0         0         1         0
5   1   sed         0         0         0         1
6   1   sed         0         0         0         1
7   1   sed         0         0         0         1
8   2   cur         1         0         0         0
9   2   sed         0         0         0         1
10  2   cur         1         0         0         0
11  2   sed         0         0         0         1
```

And here is an answer with `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = medoc,
              values_from = medoc,
              values_fn = \(x) +!is.na(x),
              values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: The latter solution gives an error on my end - is the backslash part of newer release of `pivot_wider`?  By contrast, with `values_fn = function(x) +!is.na(x)` it works

Comment: `\(x) x` is the base R lambda fuction as of R 4.0. What version are you using @Chris?

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to @Guedes's but with different `values_fn`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = medoc, values_from = medoc,
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
      id   par   mor   sed   cur
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     0     0
 2     1     0     1     0     0
 3     1     0     1     0     0
 4     1     1     0     0     0
 5     1     0     0     1     0
 6     1     0     0     1     0
 7     1     0     0     1     0
 8     2     0     0     0     1
 9     2     0     0     1     0
10     2     0     0     0     1
11     2     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Indeed, this values_fn version is a bit simpler. As I said in the comment above, I would use an even simpler version in R version 4 or higher, as in `values_fn = \(x) 1`

Comment: Thank you it is great

Answer (score 1):

Using mydata in the Note at the end and assuming that you want one row for each id with binary columns indicating which values of medoc are present (1) or absent (0) we can use table like this.  (If you would like counts instead of presence/absence then omit the pmin.)

```
pmin(table(mydata), 1)
##    medoc
## id  cur mor par sed
##  A   0   1   1   1
##  B   1   0   0   1
```

or as a data frame and adding medoc_str

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mydata %>%
  table %>%
  pmin(1) %>%
  as.data.frame.matrix %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(medoc_str = paste(names(cur_data())[c_across() == 1], collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup
## # A tibble: 2 x 6
##   id      cur   mor   par   sed medoc_str  
##   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
## 1 A         0     1     1     1 mor par sed
## 2 B         1     0     0     1 cur sed
```

### Note

Modified mydata to use better id's.

```
id <- c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 4))
medoc <- c("par", "mor", "mor", "par", "sed", "sed",
         "sed", "cur", "sed", "cur", "sed")

mydata <- data.frame(id, medoc)
```

mydata looks like this.

```
> mydata
   id medoc
1   A   par
2   A   mor
3   A   mor
4   A   par
5   A   sed
6   A   sed
7   A   sed
8   B   cur
9   B   sed
10  B   cur
11  B   sed
```

Comment: very good scripts but the initial id of patients are lost

Comment: Oops you are right. I wasn't clear. Thanks

Comment: Have changed the id's in the Note at the end to bring this out and made corresponding fixes to the code.